# In Javascript, what's an efficient way to replace adjacent duplicate phrases in a random string?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I'd like to replace duplicate phrases that appear adjacent to the original phrase in a string.
None of the phrases or strings are known at runtime.

I've tried some regex that I think should work, to replace the duplicate phrase with " | ". See below.

**Example Input String:**

`"FounderFounder Breakthrough Energy Breakthrough Energy 2015 - Present · 8 yrs2015 - Present · 8 yrs"`

**Desired Output String**

`"Founder | Breakthrough Energy | 2015 - Present · 8 yrs |"`

```
// Regex function
function replaceDuplicateSubstrings(string) {
    var regex = /(\b\w+\b)\s+\1/g;
    return string.replace(regex, "$1 |");
}
// Sample String
var exampleString = "FounderFounder Breakthrough Energy Breakthrough Energy 2015 - Present · 8 yrs2015 - Present · 8 yrs";

// Console Write
console.log(replaceDuplicateSubstrings(exampleString)); 


// Should log "Founder | Breakthrough Energy | 2015 - Present · 8 yrs |" to the console
// Instead logs the same input string with no changes: "FounderFounder Breakthrough Energy Breakthrough Energy 2015 - Present · 8 yrs2015 - Present · 8 yrs"
`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this snippet:

```js
const str = "FounderFounder Breakthrough Energy Breakthrough Energy 2015 - Present · 8 yrs2015 - Present · 8 yrs";
var repl = str.replace(/(.+?)\1/g, "$1 |");

console.log(repl)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ca2gV0/1)

RegEx Pattern `(.+?)` matches 1+ of any characters and captures it in group #1. It must be immediately followed by back-reference `\1` to make sure adjacent repeating text.